# Akka persistence on Cassandra with time to live (TTL) for events

Tags: cassandra, event-sourcing, ttl, akka-persistence, purge

In our current assignment we are using Akka with Java. We use Cassandra as an event store for persisting our domain events.

Now we have a requirement to delete events which are older than 14 days. We store millions of events per day and to avoid disk space issues on Cassandra we need to delete them after 14 days.

Cassandra has a simplistic approach to purge data with TTL. But I am not sure how to set this up from akka persistence configuration.

Please let me know if there is any way we can configure this as part of the Akka persistence journal and snapshot configurations. So that i can avoid running separate script to delete the data.

Thanks,

Vinoth

Comment: I can't answer about akka configuration. But Cassandra has two options to set TTL: for a specific column and for a table https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html. In your case the table-level ttl is more preferable because the tombstone problem will occur for your amount of deleted data in case of using column-level ttl. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html